# Can you make it so it is possible to keyboard search multi select parameters in SSRS?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

On single select parameter lists in SSRS, when the user opens the parameter list and starts typing, it automatically moves to the closest word in the list to what the user is typing. Is it possible for a multi select parameter to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, this is not possible, but a possible workaround would be to create a parameter that acts as a filter for your multi-select parameter.  This allows the user to begin typing what they want (say the letter 'B') and hit tab to go into the drop-down and it will be filtered to only items that start with 'B'.  The limitation is if you want 'A', 'B' and 'C' but not 'D' nor 'E', so in that case you would just have to not enter any values into the textbox parameter.

Comment: That's a nice idea to at least filter it down a bit with large lists. Thanks